How to use the TeamsInfo library properly?
I am using the TeamsInfo library to get the user's profile info through on_members_added. I succeeded to the my user's profile info however, my chatbot also returns the bot's detail which is undesired. I need your help to return only my info instead of both with the bot.
the ouput:
"Hi Adam!" --my info
"Welcome! We couldn't retrieve your detailed information." -- the bot's

async def on_members_added_activity(
        self, members_added: List[ChannelAccount], turn_context: TurnContext
    ):
        for member in members_added:
                
            # Attempt to get the Teams member information
            teams_member = await self.get_member(turn_context, member.id)
                
            if teams_member:
                self.full_name = f"{teams_member.given_name} {teams_member.surname}"
                self.name = teams_member.given_name
                self.email = teams_member.email
                self.organization = self.email.split("@")[1].split(".")[0]
                self.selected_option = self.organization
                        
                await turn_context.send_activity(greeting(self.name))

            else:
                self.selected_option = None
                await turn_context.send_activity("Welcome! We couldn't retrieve your detailed information.")


    async def get_member(self, turn_context: TurnContext, member_id: str) -> TeamsChannelAccount:
        try:
            if turn_context.activity.channel_data:
                member = await TeamsInfo.get_member(turn_context, member_id)
                return TeamsChannelAccount().deserialize(member.serialize())
            else:
                raise ValueError("No channel_data available in TurnContext activity.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error retrieving member: {e}")
            return None

I need your help to return only my info instead of both with the bot.

This issue is being tracked here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1863422/how-to-return-only-the-users-info-in-bot-builder-s.  Please follow above thread for further updates.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
